# Handling NaN (xsd:double) in Turtle

Tags: jena

While the special value of `NaN` is in the value space of `xsd:double`, and it can be abbreviated in Turtle, Jena 4.4.0 ( `riot --sink` ) says `Unrecognized keyword: NaN`.
Is this a Jena's specification?

1. https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf11-concepts/#xsd-datatypes
2. https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/#grammar-production-DOUBLE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A literal in Turtle in full form is *lexicalform ^^ datatype* .

`"1.234e0"^^xsd:double`

so NaN as a double is:

`"NaN"^^xsd:double`

There is an abbreviated form to allow most doubles, for example `1.234e0`.

```
[21]    DOUBLE  ::=     [+-]? ( [0-9]+ '.' [0-9]* EXPONENT   |
                                '.' [0-9]+ EXPONENT          |
                                [0-9]+ EXPONENT
                              )
```

This abbreviated form does not cover NaN so it can not be abbreviated in Turtle as defined by the standard.

It can be written in the full form.

```
:s :p "NaN"^^xsd:double .
```

which Apache Jena parses.